# Powershell Item-Property not expanded when stored to an array with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, comparison, powershell-2.0, comparison-operators, chocolatey

Writing a Posh 2.0 compliant script (a requirement), I need to get details of services using the registry base.

However when I search for a specific service using the exact name (and thus using -eq or -like), the results are incorrect while with -like using wildcards, this works as intended. How could we explain this?

```
PS > [array]$services=Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services | Where-Object {$_.PsChildName -like "*OpenVpnService*" }
PS > $services[0]


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services


SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  0   8 OpenVpnService                 {Type, Start, ErrorControl, ImagePath...}

PS > "'$($services[0].PsChildName)'"
'OpenVpnService'

PS > [array]$services=Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services | Where-Object {$_.PsChildName -eq "OpenVpnService" }
PS > $services[0]

SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  0   8

PS > "'$($services[0].PsChildName)'"
''

PS > [array]$services=Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services | Where-Object {$_.PsChildName -like "OpenVpnService" }
PS > $services[0]

    SKC  VC Name                           Property
    ---  -- ----                           --------
      0   8

PS > "'$($services[0].PsChildName)'"
''
```

**UPDATE:** Since I need a complete Posh 2.0 compliant machine, I have a brand new VM with Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate installed without any updates. Why without any updates? Because by updating the machine, I would get a more recent .NET version and Posh patches. I tested on a Windows 10 machine fully up to date and this is working flawlessly, the Windows 7 test machine also succeed as long as you do not store the output to an array.

Comment: Hi, `Get-Service` is available in PS v2, why not use it ?

Comment: Because the function I write needs to check if the service has a delayed start which can only be checked using the registry (cf. https://sqlsanctum.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/remotely-get-set-delayed-start-for-a-service-in-powershell/)

Comment: Check if it happens only with this particular service name. I couldn't reproduce the problem here.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was able to reproduce with another service name which is available by default "Power". `PS > get-childitem registry::hklm\system\CurrentControlSet\Services | where-object { $_.Name -like "*Power*" }` does not produce any output.

Comment: Btw, since I need a complete Posh 2.0 compliant machine, the device I have is a brand new Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate install without any updates. Why without any updates? Because by updating the machine, I would get a more recent .NET version and Posh patches.

Comment: I tested on a Windows 10 machine fully up to date and this is working flawlessly. The Win 7 test machine not updated at all: fails.

Comment: @sodawillow and wOxxOm. Ok. Problem solved. Thanks both for your help. I posted my answer below.

Comment: Actually, the WMI Class win32_Service actually contains the startmode. The property Startmode contains the startmode, the DelayedAutoStart (bool) indicates if this is a delayed start or not. Using WMI also makes it very easy to run this on remote machines (much easier as going through the registry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours trying to debug the situation and narrowing the issue, I have been able to determine what was causing the issue.

The array initialization/casting was failing. Simply surrounding the content that needed to be casted by [the array subexpression operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#the-array-sub-expression-operator) `@( )` solved the issue.

It seems like the way arrays are handled has changed on more recent PowerShell versions (5.1 on Windows 10, and PowerShell 2.0 on a not updated Windows 7), especially with PowerShell 3.0 which introduced [changes in collections and dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables#long-description)

```
PS > [array]$services=@(Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services | Where-Object {$_.PsChildName -like "*OpenVpnService*" })
PS > $services[0]


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services


SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  0   8 OpenVpnService                 {Type, Start, ErrorControl, ImagePath...}

PS > "'$($services[0].PsChildName)'"
'OpenVpnService'

PS > [array]$services=@(Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services | Where-Object {$_.PsChildName -eq "OpenVpnService" })
PS > $services[0]


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services


SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  0   8 OpenVpnService                 {Type, Start, ErrorControl, ImagePath...}

PS > "'$($services[0].PsChildName)'"
'OpenVpnService'

PS > [array]$services=@(Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services | Where-Object {$_.PsChildName -like "OpenVpnService" })
PS > $services[0]


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services


SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  0   8 OpenVpnService                 {Type, Start, ErrorControl, ImagePath...}

PS > "'$($services[0].PsChildName)'"
'OpenVpnService'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the service name already, you can do this:

```
$serviceName = "WinRM"

# registry
$regPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$serviceName"
[bool](Get-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name DelayedAutoStart -ErrorAction 0)

# WMI
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serviceName }).DelayedAutoStart

# result = True

$serviceName = "spooler"

# registry
$regPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$serviceName"
[bool](Get-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name DelayedAutoStart -ErrorAction 0)

# WMI
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serviceName }).DelayedAutoStart

# result = False
```

Comment: Actually I was using the `Get-WmiObject` before as a SQL request (see.: https://github.com/wget/chocolatey_openvpn/blob/4066ec675d29fd928b653b3357cf25ae6d342983/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1#L221), but using it with the `Where-Object` statement and expand the `DelayedAutoStart` property is not Posh 2.0 compliant (AFAIK). :-) I tested your code on my Posh 2.0 Windows 7 and got an exception.

Comment: @wget Edited, not tested :-)

Comment: Ok. No problem. But even in this use case, DelayedAutoStart is not Posh 2.0 compliant :-( Does not work on my Win 7, but it does on my Win 10.
Thanks, any way this is off-topic wrt. my initial question :-)

Comment: However the remaining parts of your script are working properly on Posh 2.0. Thanks for the idea of specifying the service name directly in the registry path and call the `Get-ItemProperty` Cmdlet directly on it. Also, I don't need any error check since this Cmdlet throws exceptions by default.